# Clamp animation based on two values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an animation which i want to play based on x value which is actually a position of an object.

Map Animation keys on x which start from -2 to +6. as The x become -2 animation will be on inital state as its value become increase the animation should be run further as x reached to +6 the animation should complete. Between These values at any point user decrease x values then animation should need to be reverse. I thinks it is actually clamp process where i want to map x values into key frame of the animation.

below just a simple code to run animation:

```
void Update () {
    if (isPositionChanging)
    {
        if(transform.position.x > xPos){
            if(incrementOrDecrement <=12) {
            incrementOrDecrement ++;
            AnimationPlayOnPositionValue(1, incrementOrDecrement);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (incrementOrDecrement >= 0)
            {
            incrementOrDecrement--;
            AnimationPlayOnPositionValue(1, incrementOrDecrement);
            }
        }

    }
}

void AnimationPlayOnPositionValue(float speed,float timeToUpdate) {
    animatedObject["MachineAnimationComplete"].speed = speed;
    animatedObject["MachineAnimationComplete"].time = timeToUpdate;
    animatedObject.Play();

}
```

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer or add comment(s) if you don't find the answer solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I get what you're trying to achieve correctly but I'll give it a go :

- First, I guess you forgot a `xPos = transform.position.x;` line at the end of your `Update()` : I fell like this values save the latest X position in order to compare it next frame ? (code stripping mistake I guess :P )
- Second, I think what you could do is to drive manually your Animation since you know its name : to do so you can call `AnimationClip.SampleAnimation()` method.

It would look something like :

```
void Update()
{
    float normalizedTime = Mathf.Clamp((transform.position.x - (-2.0f)) / (6.0f - (-2.0f)), 0.0f, 1.0f);
    float animationTime = normalizedTime * animatedObject["MachineAnimationComplete"].length;

    animatedObject.GetClip("MachineAnimationComplete").SampleAnimation(animatedObject.gameObject, animationTime);`
}
```

Hope this helps,